# Comparing data from single samples

Tags: statistical-significance

I measured mutations after drug treatment in two different lines (genotype A and B) at 3 different timepoints (1,2,3). Is there a test to see whether A1 is different from A2, A2 is different from A3, and A1 is different from A3? I also want to compare A1 to B1, A2 to B2 and A3 to B3. I do not know what the sampling error is at any time point.

```
time   A      B

1    186    256
2    259    313    
3    295    325
```

(I know this is not likely meaningful but a reviewer is demanding a statistical analysis on this data).

Answer (score 1):

What you might be able to do is to examine whether there are differences among times in the numbers of mutations (pooling mutation numbers from both lines) and whether the two lines differ overall (pooling information from all times). This could be done efficiently with a 2-way analysis of variance. Depending on what type of statistical analysis the reviewer is demanding, this could do the trick. As @Kontorus points out in another answer, there are underlying assumptions that would be difficult to test on such a limited data set.

In general, it's best to consult with a local statistician before starting a study, to make sure that the study design will allow for proper testing of any hypotheses that you are posing. That can minimize problems with reviewers at the end.

Comment: I have done the 2-way analyses you suggested. Unsurprisingly, they are not significant. More problematically, the comparison of those groups is not really what is of interest. I think some kind of permutation test may be in order, but I have no idea how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Without a sampling error, it should be impossible to determine if A1, A2, and A3 are statistically different from one another.

You can *theoretically* attempt to compare A and B by a comparison of means, but you only have 3 observations - your data might not be normally distributed, so any results you get from this should be taken with a grain of salt.